# Session cookie issue in the following codes. which is throwing Cannot send session cookie.. warning in php?

Tags: php

I am developing a register and login system. Through googling, fortunately, I got some readymade code from some contributor. But I am having warning messages while trying to implementing the same. I am giving here the two code snippets. Also, I want to add here that I am getting three warning messages :

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/dchcov5r/public_html/demo/application/includes/register.inc.php:1) in /home/dchcov5r/public_html/demo/application/functions.php on line 22

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/dchcov5r/public_html/demo/application/includes/register.inc.php:1) in /home/dchcov5r/public_html/demo/application/functions.php on line 22

Warning: session_regenerate_id() [function.session-regenerate-id]: Cannot regenerate session id - headers already sent in /home/dchcov5r/public_html/demo/application/functions.php on line 23

**functions.php**

```
            <?php
            ob_start();
            function sec_session_start() {
                $session_name = 'sec_session_id';   // Set a custom session name
                $secure = SECURE;
                // This stops JavaScript being able to access the session id.
                $httponly = true;
                // Forces sessions to only use cookies.
                if (ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === FALSE) {
                    header("Location: error.php?err=Could not initiate a safe session (ini_set)");
                    exit();
                }
                // Gets current cookies params.
                $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
                session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"],
                    $cookieParams["path"], 
                    $cookieParams["domain"], 
                    $secure,
                    $httponly);
                // Sets the session name to the one set above.
                session_name($session_name);
                session_start();            // Start the PHP session 
                session_regenerate_id(true);    // regenerated the session, delete the old one. 

            }

            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // database connection files
            include '../lib/config.php';
            include '../lib/opendb.php';

            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            function dLookUp($tablename,$fieldnamereq,$fieldnamegiven,$value){
            $st_rs = mysql_query("select $fieldnamereq from $tablename where $fieldnamegiven='$value'") or die("dLookUp fetch error:".mysql_error());
                if(mysql_num_rows($st_rs) == 1){
                $data = mysql_fetch_array($st_rs);
                echo $data[$fieldnamereq]; 
                }
            }

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            function login($form_no, $password, $conn) {
                // Using prepared statements means that SQL injection is not possible. 
                    $stmt = mysql_query("SELECT sl_no, name, password, salt FROM application_form_i WHERE form_no = '$form_no' LIMIT 1") or die("Error Login :".mysql_error());

                    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {
                    // get variables from result.
                    $user_id = $row['sl_no']; 
                    $db_password = $row['password']; 
                    $salt = $row['salt']; 
                    }

                    // hash the password with the unique salt.
                    $password = hash('sha512', $password . $salt);
                    if (mysql_num_rows($stmt) == 1) {
                        // If the user exists we check if the account is locked
                        // from too many login attempts 

                        if (checkbrute($user_id, $conn) == true) {
                            // Account is locked 
                            // Send an email to user saying their account is locked
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            // Check if the password in the database matches
                            // the password the user submitted.
                           if ($db_password == $password) {
                                // Password is correct!
                                // Get the user-agent string of the user.
                                $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
                                // XSS protection as we might print this value
                                $user_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $user_id);
                                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                                // XSS protection as we might print this value
                                $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512',$password . $user_browser);
                                // Login successful.
                                return true;
                            } else {
                                // Password is not correct
                                // We record this attempt in the database
                                $now = time();
                                mysql_query("INSERT INTO login_attempts(user_id, time) VALUES ('$user_id', '$now')");
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        // No user exists.
                        return false;
                    }
            }

            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            function checkbrute($user_id, $conn) {
                // Get timestamp of current time 
                $now = time();

                // All login attempts are counted from the past 2 hours. 
                $valid_attempts = $now - (2 * 60 * 60);

                $stmt = mysql_query("SELECT time FROM login_attempts WHERE user_id = $user_id AND time > '$valid_attempts'") or die("Error :".mysql_error());

                    // If there have been more than 5 failed logins 
                    if (mysql_num_rows($stmt) > 5) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
            }

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            function login_check($conn) {
                // Check if all session variables are set 
                if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'], $_SESSION['login_string'])) {

                    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
                    $login_string = $_SESSION['login_string'];

                    // Get the user-agent string of the user.
                    $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

                    $stmt = mysql_query("SELECT password FROM application_form_i WHERE sl_no = $user_id LIMIT 1");
                        if (mysql_num_rows($stmt) == 1) {
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($stmt)){
                            // If the user exists get variables from result.
                            $password = $row['password'];
                            }
                            $login_check = hash('sha512', $password . $user_browser);

                            if ($login_check == $login_string) {
                                // Logged In!!!! 
                                return true;
                            } else {
                                // Not logged in 
                                return false;
                            }
                        } else {
                            // Not logged in 
                            return false;
                        }
                } else {
                    // Not logged in 
                    return false;
                }
            }

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            function esc_url($url) {

                if ('' == $url) {
                    return $url;
                }

                $url = preg_replace('|[^a-z0-9-~+_.?#=!&;,/:%@$\|*\'()\\x80-\\xff]|i', '', $url);

                $strip = array('%0d', '%0a', '%0D', '%0A');
                $url = (string) $url;

                $count = 1;
                while ($count) {
                    $url = str_replace($strip, '', $url, $count);
                }

                $url = str_replace(';//', '://', $url);

                $url = htmlentities($url);

                $url = str_replace('&amp;', '&#038;', $url);
                $url = str_replace("'", '&#039;', $url);

                if ($url[0] !== '/') {
                    // We're only interested in relative links from $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
                    return '';
                } else {
                    return $url;
                }
            }

            ?>
```

**login.php**

```
                <?php
                include_once 'functions.php';
                sec_session_start();

                if (login_check($conn) == true) {
                    $logged = 'in';
                    header("Location: ./successpage.php?form_no=$form_no");
                    exit;
                } else {
                    $logged = 'out';
                }
                ?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before use session variable you have need to use session_start(); for start the session. before you call session_start(); if anything echo or print it can show the error "headers already sent". so for the very beginning you can call session_start();

for safety you can call in this way
if(!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

and line number 4 or 5 in your code I see $secure = SECURE; I think SECURE is not a string like "SECURE" or it's not define. Please check that also. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, but I am not printing anything before calling the function session_start(). However, I am calling the function sec_session_start() where there is a call to session_start(). Then what is wrong?